# Selenium WebDriver, can you use a Firefox driver with same history, extensions and cookies as your standard browser?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

```
string path = @"C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\l4h42jo7.Develop";
if (Directory.Exists(path))
{
    FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile(path,false);
    webDriver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
}
```

I have two questions:

1. I want to open the Firefox driver like my normal Firefox browser, with the same extensions, history and cookies. The code I've included only shares the extensions with the normal browser.
2. The Firefox profile parameter "deleteSourceOnClean" is not explained clearly by the documentation for my understanding and I don't know whether it has worked or not when specified. What does it do and how can I tell if it has worked?

Answer (score 0):

- When you open Firefox, *Selenium Web-driver* opens it with anonymous
  profile.
- We can easily open the current(default) Firefox profile or also we
  can create a new one use that with Selenium Web-driver very easily.
- To get the list of Firefox Profiles on your System you can use below
  Link.
- Very general Location is *%appdata%\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles*
  Recommended to use Links to understand more about Firefox profiles.
  [create a new Firefox profile](http://www.howtogeek.com/209320/how-to-set-up-and-use-multiple-profiles-user-accounts-in-firefox/) and [Path of Firefox profiles](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-firefox-stores-user-data)

So coming to your Question, Below code will easily use the profile created by you.

```
 ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
 FirefoxProfile ffprofile = profile.getProfile("SELENIUM");
 WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffprofile);
```

**Note:** SELENIUM is the profile I am Using in above code.

Answer (score 0):

if you are in Windows os,

Firstly make sure which 'Profile' you want. For example you would like to use the 'deafult' Profile of firefox, then copy it from %APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profile\xxxx.default to D:\default. Then code

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
File path = new File("D:\\default");
FirefoxProfile ffp =  new FirefoxProfile(path);
capabilities.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, ffp);
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("xxx"), capabilities)//or FirefoxDriver. I ignored url for RemoteWebdriver here.
```

Once you use the default profile, all of the sessions will share the extensions, cookies and so on. For your second question, so sorry i have no idea. BTW, if you want to load a existed profile in your session(especially a big profile), please set a larger heap for your jvm so that there won't be any OutofMemory Exception.